# Live Server closes when I click anywhere in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio

Hi All: I'm very new to VS Code and know no coding. I'm trying to teach myself HTML and CSS by watching videos and reading tutorials. I mention this so that perhaps will give me some understanding if my nomenclature is incorrect. 
To make a long story short through my learning's so far it sounds like VS Code is the premier code editor.
So I've downloaded and installed it. So far so good. The video I was watching introduced me to the "Live Server" extension, so I installed it. The problem is once opened, the Live Server window closes any time I left click on anything else in VS Code or if I open another Google tab. Is there a solution? Please keep in mind here my newness to coding and the VS Code editor. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Very nice extension. I installed and works fine. Maybe you need to uninstall it and install it again. But when a page in Visual Studio Code is open to install the extension you need to check the instruction how to use it. 
[image: Image Go Live]

After you open the project and your html file down in blue line in VS Code need to click the Go live button.

Comment: Hi Llazar: Thanks for the feedback, but I've tried to uninstall it and re-install 3 or 4 times as well as doing that for VS Code. I've looked for help every where I can think of to no avail. I suspect that I am not using the correct search terms which is extremely frustrating. anyway thanks again for the help. Appreciate it!